# Samba+LDAP: Minimal permissions for sambaLMPassword/sambaNTPassword?

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap

What are the minimum permissions for the attributes `sambaLMPassword`/`sambaNTPassword` for the the LDAP administrator account so that Samba is just enabled to use it for authentication for `ldapsam` backend.

It seems like `auth` is not enough, is this true?!

Answer (score 1):

In `cn=config` form I've used something like:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous
  auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=sambaLMPassword,sambaNTPassword  by dn.base="cn=admin,d
 c=example,dc=org" write  by dn.base="cn=sambaservers,dc=example,dc=org"
  write  by anonymous auth  by self write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=Computers,dc=example,dc=org" by dn.base="
 cn=sambaservers,dc=example,dc=org" manage by * read
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=Group,dc=example,dc=org" by dn.base="cn=s
 ambaservers,dc=example,dc=org" manage by * read
olcAccess: {4}to dn.exact="sambaDomainName=DOMAINNAME,dc=example,dc=org" by 
  dn.base="cn=sambaservers,dc=example,dc=org" write by * read
olcAccess: {5}to dn.base="" by * read
```

The `ou=Computers` and `ou=Group` entries are optional and only matter for smbldap-tools. The write access for the passwords by samba is also optional too. You can actually get away without giving samba write access to `sambaDomainName=DOMAINNAME,dc=example,dc=org` if you wanted to.

Samba reads the hashes, it doesn't do authentication using them.